# Sharepoint 2007 DateTime column default value?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list with a DateTime column.

I want to set the default value of the field to be like this

**December 01, 2010 1:00 PM**

what is the formula to achieve that ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

=DATE(2010;12;1)